# Yii2 How to pass the model instance to the main layout?

Tags: layout, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a change password bootstrap modal which will get triggered when the user clicks on the Change password navBar menu.

I have included the modal in the footer. But how can I pass the `ChangePassword model instance` to the footer layout file?

Can `beforeRender Or EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER` be used? If yes, How?

As suggested, I have put the following code in common/config/bootstrap.php:

```
yii\base\Event::on(yii\base\View::className(), yii\base\View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
    $modelChangePassword = new frontend\models\ChangePassword;
    $this->view->params['modelChangePassword'] = $modelChangePassword;
});
```

But its giving `Using $this when not in object context` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass it through [View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html) [params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$params-detail):

Add this in controller before rendering view:

```
$this->view->params['model'] = $model;

...

$this->render(...); // this will render your view including main layout
```

Then use in view like that:

```
$model = $this->params['model'];
```

**Update:**

If you want it globally for all application controllers you can use events:

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\View;

...

Event::on(View::className(), View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
    ...

    Yii::$app->view->params['model'] = $model;
});
```

Put this code in application bootstrap or for example in common parent Controller.

**Official docs:**

- [Events](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html)
- [Event::on()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html#on%28%29-detail)

Comment: I dont want to do that in every controller. Isn't there a common place where I can put this which will be available throughout the application?

Comment: I am getting the following error when I put it in bootstrap file: Using $this when not in object context. I have update the question Could you please have a look.