# yii2 create forms in main.php layout how to spend the $model

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

Hello everyone I am a beginner in yii2 , I have to create a form in the footer at the main.php layout section. Default does not pass the model . Could you give me an exemplary of how to pass data in the form ? Thanks so much.

Example of Controller and View.

Comment: You want pass the model in single controller action ar for all controller and action ?

Comment: For a single controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single controller action a simpel way is  use  the params .

In you controller action before render  your view you should add

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
   .....
   $this->view->params['model'] = $model;
   .....
   $this->render(...); 

}
```

and for accessing in  layout  you should retrieve using

```
$model = $this->params['model'];
```

Comment: ok , this works for single action , and if I would like to for all actions ?

Comment: You should use event  or beforeAction for setting the param ..but is bit mode complex .... anyway is what you have asked...

Comment: I think what you are trying to do can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998442/yii2-how-to-pass-the-model-instance-to-the-main-layout